# Multi Auth Guard VueJS Vue-Route Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, guard

I have a question about VueJS and the form of authentication it has, I am trying to perform a multi auth guard with beforeEnter but it does not work, I leave a job on how I want to do it to see if they can help me.

```
const isGlobal = (to, from, next) => {
    console.log('isGlobal called');
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated && store.getters.getProfile.is_global) {
        next();
        return
    }

    next(false  )
}

const isAdmin = (to, from, next) => {
    console.log('isAdmin called');
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated && store.getters.getProfile.is_admin) {
        next();
        return
    }

    next(false)
}
const isSupervisor = (to, from, next) => {
    console.log('isSupervisor called');
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated && store.getters.getProfile.is_supervisor) {
        next();
        return
    }

    next(false)
}

const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        beforeEnter: [isSupervisor || isGlobal || isAdmin],
    }
];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `[isSupervisor || isGlobal || isAdmin]` is an array equals to `[false]` or `[true]`, it must be a function. Try something like this:

```
const isGlobal = store.getters.isAuthenticated && store.getters.getProfile.is_global

const isAdmin = store.getters.isAuthenticated && store.getters.getProfile.is_admin

const isSupervisor = store.getters.isAuthenticated && store.getters.getProfile.is_supervisor

const conditionalNext = function(condition) { 
    return (to, from, next) => {
        if (condition) {
            next();
            return
        }
        next(false)
    }
}

    const routes = [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
            beforeEnter: conditionalNext(isSupervisor || isGlobal || isAdmin)
        }
    ];
```